# Replacing specific value on pandas with edited value of row

Tags: pandas, regex, dataframe, replace

I need to replacing a specific selected value of row with value that has been edited, what method that I need to do this? For example, I need to replace only the value chosen that contains `'X KODYA'` with a new value `'KOTA X'`

For example:

```
+----------------+
|       A        |
+----------------+
| SURABAYA KODYA |
| JAKARTA        |
| KEDIRI KODYA   |
+----------------+
```

Into:

```
+----------------+
|       A        |
+----------------+
| KOTA SURABAYA  |
| JAKARTA        |
| KOTA KEDIRI    |
+----------------+
```

For now what I do is replacing it manually:

```
df['A'] = df['A'].str.replace('KEDIRI KODYA', 'KOTA KEDIRI').str.replace('SURABAYA KODYA', 'KOTA SURABAYA')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a regex with a capturing group and [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df['A'] = df['A'].str.replace(r'(\w+)\s+KODYA', r'KOTA \1', regex=True)
```

output:

```
               A
0  KOTA SURABAYA
1        JAKARTA
2    KOTA KEDIRI
```